# OSX El Capitan - Apache 403 Forbidden

Tags: macos, apache, osx-elcapitan

I just upgraded from Yosemite to El Capitan but unfortunately forgot to copy my old httpd.conf and now i need to configure all of its settings again.

I already changed the documentroot to the previous one /users/admin/www, and also configured to release access to this folder:

```
<Directory "/users/admin/www">
Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Restarted Apache but even this way I get the 'Forbidden' error when trying to access 127.0.0.1.

What am I'm missing here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I just found out that the old .conf file is saved during the El Captain update, in this folder :

/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf.pre-update

So i just copied the old definitions to the new one :)

Comment: While the accepted answer works and is easy to do, it doesn't specifically address the problem. Restoring the old apache configs rolls back any updates to made to the apache configuration made for El Captain... sorta like fixing a broken lamp by using a candle instead (in a hyperbolic kinda way). @jcfranco and Todd Hammer have some answers below that specifically address the permissions problem.

Answer (score 73):

Do the following:

- Open Terminal
- Run:

  ```
  cd /etc/apache2/
  sudo mv httpd.conf httpd.conf.OLD
  sudo mv httpd.conf~previous httpd.conf
  sudo apachectl restart
  ```

After spending 3 hours on the issue - this **worked** for me!

Comment: If you have a brand new Mac use this as the third command:


`sudo mv httpd.conf.pre-update httpd.conf`


You really, really saved my day!

Comment: This answer will probably work for most people as it addresses the main problem - your httpd.conf file is now incorrect. It didn't work for me however but this great guide https://medium.com/@JohnFoderaro/how-to-set-up-apache-in-os-x-10-11-el-capitan-637b30fe67b1#.z0w006fdo got to me to update my httpd.conf to a place where it now works

Comment: This worked for my 10.14.6 running on a 2017 MacBook.  I'm very curious what you accomplished in those commands.  It looks like you're restoring httpd.conf to a previous version, but why does this work??

Answer (score 9):

You can navigate to `/private/etc/apache2/` and then `diff httpd.conf httpd.conf.pre-update` to see the differences between your old conf file and the new one that's been added.

For me there was a lot of `LoadModules` lines commented out, and my apache user/group had been changed back to `_www`

Answer (score 5):

I am not familiar with the changes in Apache 2.4 so this one really stumped me for about 30 minutes. I just upgraded from Mavericks to El Capitan (Apache 2.2 to 2.4) and I could not load my personal Sites directory (http://localhost/~{username}. I kept getting "Forbidden". After a good bit of research I found that I needed to modify /etc/apache2/users/{username}.conf to add "Require all granted". Since I never upgraded to Yosemite (which also uses Apache 2.4) I never stumbled across this one.

I hope this info helps somebody

Comment: Good one, saved my day. Don't forget to add this definition on your /etc/apache2/extras/httpd-vhosts.conf if you use virtualhosts ;)

Answer (score 4):

Updating the directory access control worked for me:

> In this example, all requests are allowed.
>
> 2.2 configuration:
>
> `Order allow,deny Allow from all`
>
> 2.4 configuration:
>
> `Require all granted`

Source: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/upgrading.html (under Access control)

**Note**: I keep my custom settings separately under `/private/etc/apache2/other/`.

Answer (score 3):

This helped as well (after doing everything else as well):

http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/forbidden-403-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-username-on-this-server/

Answer (score 2):

Like @delphirules said, you can copy your old httpd.conf file like so:

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/httpd.conf.pre-update /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

I’ve had issues with connecting to my localhost all day but finally found this: https://mallinson.ca/web-development-with-el-capitan/

Just run the copy command and then do a `sudo apachectl restart`

I’ve also disabled the SIP ( System Integrity Protection ) in recovery mode. I don’t know if it actually did anything though.. You can find those instructions here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/3981

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue receiving a 404 error back when trying to access pages in my local sites directory after enabling myself at the user level to serve sites after upgrading to El Capitan. The issue was that Apache reset the httpd.conf file to its default which disables the user folders to load files from. So http://localhost loaded fine but http://localhost/~username/index.html would NOT load. Here's the fix:

back up the "new" config file that was created:

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/httpd.conf /etc/apache2/httpd.conf_capitan
```

restore the "old" config file that was renamed:

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/httpd.conf~previous /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you have symlinks to some of your projects in DocumentRoot directory, after upgrade to El Capitan you can get 403 for these projects, like I did.
You will need the following things to make them work again:

1) Your apache user (_www by default) should have execute access to directory that houses a directory to which you link to.
In my case in apache DocumentRoot I had:

```
MyProject -> /Users/Me/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/MyProject
```

And for some reason access settings for
`/Users/Me/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/MyProject`
were
`-rw-------   1 Me  staff` My guess it was set during OS x upgrade.
So after `sudo chmod 755 Aptana\ Studio\ 3\ Workspace` error was resolved.

2) As upgrade also changes httpd.conf, make sure you have this for DocumentRoot directory, or restore from backup httpd.conf as suggested above:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
```

If you upgraded from Mavericks or earlier OS x and restored backup httpd.conf, you should, as jcfranko said, replace apache 2.2 setting for request allowance with:

```
Require all granted
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a symlink in your `/Users/{user name}/Sites` folder

```
ln -s /Path/To/Target/Files /Users/{user name}/Sites/{name}
```